# Every command typed in terminal gets written "double"?

Tags: mac, terminal, macos-bigsur

If i open terminal a type a command it works fine.

As soon as i connect to a specific device everytime i type a character it types "double" making it impossible to type anything

Please see screenshot below. (ive typed the word "admin") I would presume this is a terminal issue rather than a device issue as i havnt even pressed return to send the command to the device.

Im running Big Sur on a Macbook Pro, ive tried with both the standard shell and the zsh shell.

Any ideas ?

[image: screenshot from terminal]

Comment: Are you able to log in? (ignore the feedback and just try). Are you able to run commands? I mean if you type `ls` then you will probably see `llss` echoed; but will the remote computer try to execute `ls` or `llss`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it wont let me run commands as i cant get past the username/password stage. It would accept my username/password either unfortuantley

Comment: *"... making it impossible to type anything"* -- Why?  You were able to successfully enter a username; i.e. there's a prompt for a password.  *"... it types "double""* --  Because you have both local echo (a terminal property/mode) and remote echo (performed by the connected device).  Turn off local echo (disabled should be the default mode unless you're connected to a device that does not echo).

Comment: *"Every command typed in terminal gets written double"* versus *"it wont let me run commands ..."* -- Contradictory descriptions.